# Simplifying mysql calls into 1 update

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to simplify multiple queries into 1 and for some reason I am having issues.  I would like to update a reference count in a table while counting the ref in another table.  Currently all I have is the _Doc_ID from the first table.  I would like to look up the _FilePath and then count the number of rows that have the same _FilePath.  Then Update the Ref_Count by the number found.

> table 1

```
| _Doc_ID | Ref_Count |
|    1    |           |
```

> table 2

```
| ID  |  _FilePath |
|  1  |  123/123   |
|  2  |  123/123   |
```

> Expected Results Table 1

```
| _Doc_ID | Ref_Count |
|    1    |     2     |
```

> first query

```
SELECT _FilePath AS FilePathResult from database.tableName where _Doc_ID = '1'
```

> second

```
SELECT count(*) AS TotalCount from database.tableName where _FilePath = FilePathResult
```

> Third

```
Update table1 SET Ref_Count = TotalCount where _Doc_ID = 1
```

Comment: @sebastianbrosch : Re-post your answer.  It was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` with `sub-query` will do.

```
Update table1 
SET Ref_Count = 
    (
        SELECT count(*) AS TotalCount from database.tableName 
        where _FilePath = (SELECT _FilePath AS FilePathResult from database.tableName where _Doc_ID = '1')
    )
where _Doc_ID = 1
```